# link array data based on the same keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Array**

```
[
  code: 'code',
  specName: [
              0: 'First',
              1: 'Second',
              2: 'Third'
            ],
  year: [
              0: '2011',
              1: '2012',
              2: '2013'
            ]
];
```

**The Lowdown**

I am using AngularJS to output the data, using `ng-repeat="name in module.specName"`. What I would like to do is link `year[0]` with `specName[0]` and so forth. So my output will look like:

```
 -------------------
| specName |  year  |
 -------------------
|  First   |   2011 |
 -------------------
|  Second  |   2012 |
 -------------------
|  Third   |   2013 |
 -------------------
```

**Question**

Could I be pointed in the right direction of how I could go about achieving this. Is there an angular `.filter` that I have to write or some data re-structuring in the angular app or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.specName">
    <span>{{value}}</span>
    <span>{{data.year[key]}}</span>         
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.data={
    code: 'code',
    specName: {
        0: 'First',
        1: 'Second',
        2: 'Third'
    },
    year: {
        0: '2011',
        1: '2012',
        2: '2013'
    }
};
```

Comment: ah thank you! didn't know about (key, value) pairings in ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to restructure your data like this:

```
$scope.data = {
  code: 'code',
  specs: [
     {name: 'First', year:2011 },
     {name: 'Second', year:2012 },
     {name: 'Third', year:2013 }
  ]
};
```

So you'll be able to display it very easy:

```
 <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="spec in data.specs">
        <td>{{spec.name}}</td>
        <td>{{spec.year}}</td>  
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ka8jM8?p=preview